# Return deconstructed array in object with es6 map

Tags: javascript, arrays, chain

I want to return a deconsturcted array so I only get single element in te returned array instead of array.

```js
const data = [
 {
    title: 'amsterdam',
    components: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'yanick',    
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'ronald',    
      },
    ],  
  },
  
  {
    title: 'rotterdam',
    components: [
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'nicky',    
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'casper',    
      },
    ],  
  },
];

const test = data
  .map(item => {
    console.log(item.components);
    return item.components;
  }).map(array => {
   // how to get comibned components here?
    // it can't use ...item.components (deconstructing or something)
  });
  
console.log('test', test);
```

So I want to use chained map functions to create one array of all elements in `item.components`. Is this possible? Seems like I can't deconstruct the array of each item.

Comment: you wan to reduce your array ? `.reduce` is already there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.prototype.reduce` seems like the correct method to use in this context.

```
const test = data.reduce( (result, current) => result.concat(current.components) , []);

console.log('test', test);
```

Output

```
test [ { id: 1, name: 'yanick' },
  { id: 2, name: 'ronald' },
  { id: 4, name: 'nicky' },
  { id: 3, name: 'casper' } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the `components` with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and flatten by spreading into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const data = [{"title":"amsterdam","components":[{"id":1,"name":"yanick"},{"id":2,"name":"ronald"}]},{"title":"rotterdam","components":[{"id":4,"name":"nicky"},{"id":3,"name":"casper"}]}];

const result = [].concat(...data.map(o => o.components));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get data combined into single array you can use `reduce` in combination with `concat` that will create a single array of results.

```js
const data = [
 {
    title: 'amsterdam',
    components: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'yanick',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'ronald',
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    title: 'rotterdam',
    components: [
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'nicky',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'casper',
      },
    ],
  },
];

const test = data
  .map(item => {
    return item.components;
  }).reduce((res, item) => {
    return res.concat(item);
  }, []);

console.log('test', test);
```

Comment: You don't need `.map` as well. :)

Comment: Yes, I have just filled the place that OP asked to be filled :)